# Delphi - issue with drawing over a TDBGrid descendant

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I've wrote a TDBGrid descendant component which is displaying the content of different blob fields for the current row selected, each one in a TJvDBRichEdit. The [DrawColumnCell](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.DrawColumnCell) code for displaying the content of the blob fields:

```
procedure TMyDBGrid.DrawColumnCell(const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var iPos,iNr,iTop:Integer;
begin
 // RBA 01/04/2013 12:10
if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
 if FDisplayBlobAsRTF then //property to show the blob fields or not
  begin
  if (gdSelected in State) then
    begin
     if Column.Field.isblob then
      begin
        ipos := 0;
        iNr := 0;
        while (iPos <= Column.Field.DataSet.FieldCount-1)and(Column.Field.DataSet.Fields[ipos].FieldName <> Column.Field.FieldName ) do
         begin
          if Column.Field.DataSet.Fields[ipos].IsBlob then
           inc(iNr);
          inc(iPos);
         end;
        with TJvDBRichEdit(FRichEditList[inr]) do//FRichEditList - TObjectList which contains all the TJvDBRichEdit components, and release them on destroy
         begin
          Left := Rect.Left + Self.Left + 1;
          iTop :=  Rect.Top + Self.Top + 1;
          if iTop + Height > Self.Height then
           iTop := iTop - Height;
          Top := iTop;
          Width := Rect.BottomRight.X - Rect.left;

          Visible := true;
         end;
      end;
    end
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

overrided [LayoutChanged](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/API:Vcl.DBGrids.TGridDataLink.LayoutChanged) routine

```
procedure TMyDBGrid.LayoutChanged;
var iPos : Integer;
    dtDataset : TDataSet;
    jvDbRichEdit : TJvDBRichEdit;
begin
 if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
 if FDisplayBlobAsRTF then
  begin
    dtDataset := GetDataset;//get the dataset assigned to the grid
    if dtDataset <> nil then
    if dtDataset.State <> dsInactive then
     begin
      FRichEditList.Clear;
      for iPos := 0 to dtDataset.FieldCount-1 do
       if dtDataset.Fields[iPos].IsBlob then
        begin
         jvDbRichEdit := TJvDBRichEdit.Create(nil);
         jvDbRichEdit.Parent := Self;
         jvDbRichEdit.DataSource := Self.DataSource;
         jvDbRichEdit.DataField := dtDataset.Fields[iPos].FieldName;
         jvDbRichEdit.Visible := false;
         FRichEditList.Add(jvDbRichEdit);
        end;
     end;
  end;
end;
```

the problem appears when I make a scroll on the last displayed grid row :

[image]

How can I redraw the grid behind? I've tried with repainting the hole grid, but it is flickering.

LE: this is not intended to modify the content in the richedtis, only to display them.

Comment: You will need at least adjust the height for each row (through the [`RowHeights`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.RowHeights) property) which differs in height from the [`DefaultRowHeight`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.DefaultRowHeight) value. Though I can't suggest you a good event for doing so at this time.

Comment: The `DrawColumnCell` method is intended for *drawing* the cell. It's really not designed for re-arranging child controls. Have you considered abandoning the edit control and just [painting the cell contents](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/windowless-rtf)? Then you can configure a single edit control for use during in-place editing instead of managing a list of dozens of children.

Comment: @RobKennedy - I don't want at this moment to edit the blobs, I need only to display them correctly.

Comment: Then don't use an edit control at all. Just display the RTF.

Comment: @RobKennedy - If I use the TJvDbRichEdit, and not put the dataset behind into edit mode, I'm only displaying the data. Maybe I don't understand what you want to explain.

Comment: Why use an entirely separate UI control to *display* a value? Is there a TEdit control to display the single-line values in the grid? I doubt it. The grid just paints those values with Canvas.TextOut. I'm suggesting that you just *paint* the RTF field's value onto the grid as well.